# Getting NSDate of yesterday at 12:00 and tonight

Tags: objective-c

Lets say its now morning in my place 10:00AM .
I need to get 2 `NSDates` , one of yesterday(or today) night at 12:01 , and the other of today at 11:59 at night (sorry i am little bit confused with AM and PM, and i don't want it to mess the question ).

I have seen here something like this :

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
//intervals taken from Google
NSDate *yesterday = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -86400.0];
```

But this number is a const.
How would i subtract from now's date what is needed to get today's 12:01 at night (past) and todays 11:59 at night (future) ?
Thanks.

Comment: Look at `NSDateComponents`

Comment: Do not use 12*60 or something like that. Better use NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write your own logic as you need

You will get the NSDate components using

`NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];
NSInteger hours = [components hour];
NSInteger mins = [components minute];
NSInteger secs = [components second];`

Now you can change the hours and mins a

`hours -= 10;
 mins -= 120`

Now again the form the date object

`[date setHour:hours];
 [date setMinute:mins];`

Comment: thanks a lot . but still i have to calculate the distance from now to yesterday  and add it ..